# How can I search all plugins for composer's vendor/autoload.php?

Tags: php, plugin-development, theme-development, composer

I've got projects (both themes and plugins) set up as composer projects. These projects can be dev-dependencies of each other. Right now I'm working on a theme which requires the `vendor/autoload.php` file. However, when I bring that theme into another project (like a plugin), I still need access to the `autoload.php`. The problem is that the `autoload.php` file is now inside the directory structure for the plugin and not the theme.

```
define('FL_CHILD_THEME_DIR', get_stylesheet_directory());
define('FL_CHILD_THEME_URL', get_stylesheet_directory_uri());

if (!file_exists(FL_CHILD_THEME_DIR . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
  // somehow check all the directories within the plugins directory 
  // for vendor/autoload.php
} else {
    require FL_CHILD_THEME_DIR . '/vendor/autoload.php';
  }
}
```

I've tried using things like `scandir` and `glob` but I'm not getting any closer. I thought something like this would work, but I'm still no closer.

```
foreach(glob(plugin_dir_path() . 'vendor/autoload.php') as $file {
  require $file;
}
```

Comment: Normally you would have a project level `composer.json` so that there's a singular `vendor` folder in `wp-content` that's loaded which contains the shared dependencies. Then the WP custom installer would make sure the themes and plugins themselves went to the right folders rather than the `vendor` folder. The situation you're in shouldn't occur, can you give us some more context as to the structure?

Answer (score 1):

Autoloader setup:

```
"autoload"   : {
   "files"   : ["functions.php"]
}
```

Once you have the autoloader setup properly, you just need to include that one file, like this:

```
require_once( 'vendor/autoload.php' );
```

Full tutorial here - https://torquemag.io/2014/11/improving-wordpress-plugin-development-composer/

Comment: Thanks! This was a good read. It turned out not to quite fit my needs though. I was able to resolve the issue by mapping the vendor folder inside my docker-compose file.